# Count number of times array contains string per category in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I begin with the spark array "df_spark":

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Word Count").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()

np.random.seed(0)
rows = 6
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame({ 'color' : pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(["blue","orange", "red"], rows)),
   'animal' : [['cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'monkey'], ['monkey', 'cat'], ['dog', 'monkey'], ['cat', 'dog'], ['monkey', 'dog']]})

print(df_pandas)
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)
df_spark.show()
```

I want to end up with a new spark table "df_results_spark", that counts the occurrence of each of the strings "cat", "monkey", "dog" in the array per category "red, blue, orange".

```
df_results_pandas = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red', 'blue', 'orange'],
                                      'cat': [0, 2, 2],
                                  'dog': [1, 1, 2],
                                  'monkey': [1, 1, 2]})

print(df_results_pandas)
df_results_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_results_pandas)
df_results_spark.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `explode()` function to create one row per element in the array.

```
df_spark_exploded = df_spark.selectExpr("color","explode(animal) as animal")
df_spark_exploded.show()

+------+------+
| color|animal|
+------+------+
|  blue|   cat|
|  blue|   dog|
|orange|   cat|
|orange|monkey|
|  blue|monkey|
|  blue|   cat|
|orange|   dog|
|orange|monkey|
|orange|   cat|
|orange|   dog|
|   red|monkey|
|   red|   dog|
+------+------+
```

Then reshape the dataframe using `pivot()` and applying count aggregate function to get count of each animal.

```
df_results_spark = df_spark_exploded.groupby("color").pivot("animal").count().fillna(0)
df_results_spark.show()

+------+---+---+------+
| color|cat|dog|monkey|
+------+---+---+------+
|orange|  2|  2|     2|
|   red|  0|  1|     1|
|  blue|  2|  1|     1|
+------+---+---+------+
```